# python: how to multiply each value in a list against all the values in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x

EDIT2: I have removed the rest of the code so I don't spoil the solution. Thank you for your help.

EDIT: I included my whole code. I didn't want to include it because I didn't want to spoil the solution for anyone trying this problem themselves. But I want help so here it is.

I manually am accomplishing this by doing the following but I want this to work on a bigger scale and I refuse to manually copy and paste it that many times. That's not the point of writing code.

```
x = []
y = []

for i in range(len(x)-1):
products.append(x[0] * y[i])
products.append(x[1] * y[i])
products.append(x[2] * y[i])
products.append(x[3] * y[i])
products.append(x[4] * y[i])
products.append(x[5] * y[i])
products.append(x[6] * y[i])
products.append(x[7] * y[i])
products.append(x[8] * y[i])
products.append(x[9] * y[i])
products.append(x[10] * y[i])
products.append(x[11] * y[i])
products.append(x[12] * y[i])
products.append(x[13] * y[i])
products.append(x[14] * y[i])
products.append(x[15] * y[i])
products.append(x[16] * y[i])
products.append(x[17] * y[i])
products.append(x[18] * y[i])
products.append(x[19] * y[i])
products.append(x[20] * y[i])
products.append(x[21] * y[i])
products.append(x[22] * y[i])
products.append(x[23] * y[i])
products.append(x[24] * y[i])
products.append(x[25] * y[i])
products.append(x[26] * y[i])
products.append(x[27] * y[i])
products.append(x[28] * y[i])
products.append(x[29] * y[i])
products.append(x[30] * y[i])
products.append(x[31] * y[i])
products.append(x[32] * y[i])
products.append(x[33] * y[i])
products.append(x[34] * y[i])
products.append(x[35] * y[i])
products.append(x[36] * y[i])
products.append(x[37] * y[i])
products.append(x[38] * y[i])
products.append(x[39] * y[i])
products.append(x[40] * y[i])
products.append(x[41] * y[i])
products.append(x[42] * y[i])
products.append(x[43] * y[i])
products.append(x[44] * y[i])
products.append(x[45] * y[i])
products.append(x[46] * y[i])
products.append(x[47] * y[i])
products.append(x[48] * y[i])
products.append(x[49] * y[i])
products.append(x[50] * y[i])
products.append(x[51] * y[i])
products.append(x[52] * y[i])
products.append(x[53] * y[i])
products.append(x[54] * y[i])
products.append(x[55] * y[i])
products.append(x[56] * y[i])
products.append(x[57] * y[i])
products.append(x[58] * y[i])
products.append(x[59] * y[i])
products.append(x[60] * y[i])
products.append(x[61] * y[i])
products.append(x[62] * y[i])
products.append(x[63] * y[i])
products.append(x[64] * y[i])
products.append(x[65] * y[i])
products.append(x[66] * y[i])
products.append(x[67] * y[i])
products.append(x[68] * y[i])
products.append(x[69] * y[i])
products.append(x[70] * y[i])
products.append(x[71] * y[i])
products.append(x[72] * y[i])
products.append(x[73] * y[i])
products.append(x[74] * y[i])
products.append(x[75] * y[i])
products.append(x[76] * y[i])
products.append(x[77] * y[i])
products.append(x[78] * y[i])
products.append(x[79] * y[i])
products.append(x[80] * y[i])
products.append(x[81] * y[i])
products.append(x[82] * y[i])
products.append(x[83] * y[i])
products.append(x[84] * y[i])
products.append(x[85] * y[i])
products.append(x[86] * y[i])
products.append(x[87] * y[i])
products.append(x[88] * y[i])
products.append(x[89] * y[i])
```

I know that if you are repeating code you are doing it wrong. I can't figure out how to get this to work.

I tried x[i] * y[i] but that just takes the first value from each and multiplies them.

I tried putting another for loop inside but that didn't work either (same result).

I tried a while loop with j = 0 and having it increase j by 1 each time but that didn't work either (same result).

Please help me understand how I can do this. I know it's possible. I have been practicing in python for a week so please give me a break, I know this is a stupid question.

Comment: Please tell us your input and expected output.

Comment: ok I will edit with the whole code

Comment: @McGrady I have edited with whole code. I didn't want to spoil the solution but here it is. I know this works for the test case and I want to expand it to work for the problem statement but there's no way I will copy and paste it that many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to do

```
for i in range(10, 100):
    x.append(i)
```

You can make a list from a `range` object like this:

```
x = list(range(10, 100))
```

However, there's no need to make those `x` and `y` lists. You can create a list of the products by iterating directly over the ranges. For example:

```
products = []
for x in range(10, 100):
    for y in range(10, 100):
        products.append(x * y)
```

To make a list just containing the palindromes:

```
def is_palindrome(n):
    s = str(n)
    return s == s[::-1]

products = []
for x in range(10, 100):
    for y in range(10, 100):
        n = x * y
        if is_palindrome(n):
            products.append(n)
```

You can then do `max(products)` to find the highest palindrome that is the product of two two-digit numbers.

Here's a more compact way, using a generator expression, so it doesn't need to build a list:

```
r = range(10, 100)
print(max(filter(is_palindrome, (x * y for x in r for y in r))))
```

Comment: Holy sht. You just condensed my entire code that has taken me 3 days on and off into two lines. Are you a wizard

Comment: ...and it ran instantly. I don't know who you are but to me what you have just done is legendary. My only question is why does is_palindrome not require the parameter 'n' when it is in your 'generator expression'?

Comment: @vampiire Well, I _have_ been using Python for over 10 years, and programming in various languages for several decades, so I've learned a few tricks. :) But that "one-liner" isn't really that advanced, once you know about [generator expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) and the [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use nested loop

```
x = []
y = []
products = []
palindromes = []

for i in range(10, 100):
    x.append(i)
# print(x)

for i in range(10, 100):
    y.append(i)
# print(y)

for i in range(len(y)):
    for j in range(len(x)):
        products.append(x[j] * y[i])


for i in range((len(products)-1)):
    a = str(products[i])
    b = tuple(a)
    c = b[::-1]
    if b == c:
        print('palindrome found!', a)
        print('b value:', b)
        print('c value:', c)
        palindromes.append(a)

solutions = list(map(int, palindromes))
solutions.sort()
print(solutions)
```

This is called the nested loop. Variable i is iterating for length of y minus 1 and variable j is iterating for length of x minus 1.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't give me the same result. Let me try again maybe (more than likely) I messed up.

Comment: no this does not work. does not produce the same result as the manual copy / paste way I had before. Any suggestion?

Comment: @vampiire It should work, as I did the same thing and I see the same output. So I have integrated the solution with your actual code.

Comment: try this code please. you will see you get the answer 8448 as the maximum palindrome. in my original (copy/paste) code I got the proper answer of 9009.

Comment: @vampiire yes.. I added -1 by mistake. It will work now

Comment: I made the same mistake! Ah this has been driving me to the point of manually typing out 90 times. That is how frustrated and certain I was the rest of the code would work. Thank you. Point awarded.

Comment: Now I am just wondering why I needed -1 when I copy/paste but now I longer need it. Any thoughts?

Comment: @vampire When you write for x in range(5) this means loop will run for 0, 1, 2, 3 & 4. Loop will not run for 5. You can check that by typing list(range(5)) in python. You will see a [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] are generated.

Comment: Thank you I understood that. I am wondering why initially in my crude copy paste solution I was using len(x)-1 in range and it was working properly. Anyways I got the right answer, I am the 335174th person to solve it! Small victory. Goodnight thank you again for your help.

Comment: What's the point of `b = tuple(a)`? Just see if the `a` string is a palindrome by comparing it to `a[::-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is equivalent to this:

```
products=[i*j for i in x[:-1] for j in y]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Kaushal Kumar Singh's solution, or here are two other solutions. However, in programming there is no universal solution, a lot of solutions can co-exist.

Code 1:

```
products = [i * j for i, j in zip(x, y)]
```

Code 2:

```
from operator import mul

products = list(map(mul, x, y))
```

Comment: That just multiplies corresponding elements of the 2 lists together, i.e. `x[0]*y[0], x[1]*y[1]`, etc. That's not what the OP wants to do.

Comment: Exactly. It comes down to nested for loops. My problem when I tried this was using len(x)-1 instead of just len(x) for the ranges.