# Regarding variable storage

Tags: python, performance

I have just finished writing an optimised solution for Project Euler's fourth problem. While I was implementing the algorithm, I experienced some internal conflict over design choices. I was uncertain whether I should store a product of an operation in its own variable, for future reference, or instead not store it as variable and reproduce the product of the two operands whenever required. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
product = x * y
if (checkPalindrome(product) and product > largest_product):
    largest_product = product
```

The operand is stored in 'product' and is referenced in the following lines. The curiosity I have is whether this is considered to be the better practice when compared to reproducing the product whenever a reference to it is required. Like this:

```
if (checkPalindrome(x * y) and x * y > largest_product):
    largest_product = x * y
```

Can this difference in implementation yield a difference in space, or time performance when scaled?

Comment: It would perform multiplication multiple times. There is no guarantee that multiplication between two objects will always return same value, so interpreter cannot make this assumption.

Comment: FWIW, you may find [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42713716/4014959) of interest...

Answer (score 0):

In practice, the first approach is best. Since here, you are multiplying small integers, so it doesn't impact that much in the later approach. But, when you run this inside a loop, for calculation of number of products, then it really maters and impacts as well.

Let's assume you have 10 loops. In the second approach, if your one multiplication takes O(1) time. So, within a loop, you will have 2 such calculations, hence it will take O(2) times. For 10 such loops, you will have O(20) times.

```
if (checkPalindrome(x * y) and x * y > largest_product):  # O(1)
    largest_product = x * y       # O(1)
# total O(2) for two calculations
```

But, in the first approach, since you are doing the calculation only once, and in later steps utilizing the calculated values, so it will take only O(1) time, only during the calculation. But, no time, while you will reference it for condition checking. For 10 such loops, you will have O(10) times. Thus you are saving 50 % of your time.

```
product = x * y    # O(1) for one calculation
if (checkPalindrome(product) and product > largest_product):
    largest_product = product
```

Yes, if memory is a constraint, then for storing variable, you might need memory. And in that case you might think of second approach. Or if there is a single point of calculation, then in that case, you are good to go with the second approach. But, for the first case, where memory is constraint, it would not take significant amount of memory just to store a variable. So, anyway, I find the first one (calculating once and storing rather than calculating each time) as the best and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Arithmetic in Python isn't particularly fast, so it's better to avoid performing the same computation multiple times. BTW, rather than determining the maximum product "by hand" you could do it with the built-in `max` function.

I should also mention that you aren't saving much RAM by avoiding doing `product = x * y`. The code still has to create an `int` object to hold the result of `x * y` anyway, binding that object to a name doesn't consume much RAM. OTOH, performing the same calculation 3 times not only wastes time, it means that 3 objects need to be created (and recycled) to store the result.

I suggest you take a look at [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables). For a more in-depth examination of this important topic, please see [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: The links are good, but I'll note here that while "other languages have variables (instead of names)" is true, it's not the case that *all* other languages have variables (instead of names)": Python is merely in a large group of languages, including the grand-daddy of them all—Lisp—that use this general "values bound (for some time) to names" scheme (or should I say Scheme? :-) ).

Comment: @torek Certainly! Those articles are (mostly) aimed at people coming from the C family and other languages that use the "variable as a box" data model. I've never used Lisp itself, although I have used a couple of Lisp-like languages a little bit (but that was quite a few years ago). My main experience with the "objects that may be bound to names" model comes from PostScript.

Answer (score 0):

A number takes an amount of storage proportional to its length (when printed out). For modest sized numbers, up to 20 digits say, you are not likely to notice this effect at all. Above that you are not likely to notice the effect unless you have huge numbers (thousands of digits) or lots of them.

The multiplication of two numbers takes... well, this is an active area of research, but for these purposes let's say it takes time proportional to the square of the length (when printed out) of the longest number (if they are similar in length). But again, you aren't likely to notice this effect unless you have huge numbers.

As others have observed, multiplication is not quick in Python, so that's a concern.

I suggest you write what's clearest and then clean up your performance problems when you encounter them.